# How to use Hibernate Query|Criteria.scroll() with DISTINCT without duplications

Tags: java, hibernate

I have implemented usage of `ScrollableResults` for big DB table, everything worked perfectly until I wanted to do the same for another table using joins.

The entity where I have the problem has some one-to-many associations so I have to use `DISTINCT` not to get duplicates. Everything works well when I am obtaining results of the query using `list()`. But when I use `scroll()`, `DISTINCT` seems to be ignored completely - I just get many duplicates.

```
Query query = gameSession.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT c FROM City c JOIN FETCH c.inhabitans i");
```

This works well, list has no duplicates:

```
List<City> list = query.list();
```

This is does not work (giving many duplicates like there would be no DISTINCT used):

```
ScrollableResults sr = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
```

Everything is the same when I use Criteria instead of Query. I have found out only 3 things about this particular problem:

1. Few questions like mine without answer,
2. A [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3694) describing a case that could be absolutely the same like mine, but that should have been fixed long time ago,
3. Little comment in one of the SO answers telling that "DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY does not interact very well when `scroll()` is used".

This makes `ScrollableResults` useless for me, but I still need it because of the huge memory save. Do you know **how to achieve scrolling results with `DISTINCT` used?** Or any workaround?

Hibernate version: 4.2.4; JDK 7; DB: MSSQL

Comment: have you tried converting it to criteria + CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY?

Comment: Yes, result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add an "order by" clause to your query with the Id of the root entity.